# Figure beneath itemize list in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning

I want to make an itemized list with a figure underneath using `beamer`. However, I want the figure to appear only with the first bullet of the list. The problem is then that using `\includegraphics<1>{fig}` will cause the itemized list to jump around. This I solved using `overprint`, however adding more items to the list will reserve more space for all items, and place the figure below the list item, even though it is not visible at the time the figure is shown. I also tried placing the figure in the `itemize` environment, but that will leave room between items in the list.

I would like to be able to place a figure below an itemized list, where it is associated with a certain bullet point in the list, and will be placed directly underneath that point, without already leaving room for other items in the list.

MWE (showing the current option with overprint):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Minimal Working Example}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> This item belongs with the figure
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> as well as this sub item
        \end{itemize}
        \item<2-> This shows after the figure
        \item<3-> But still takes up space
        \item<4-> For long lists, the figure will not be visible anymore
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics{fig}
        \end{figure}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this give the expected output?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Minimal Working Example}
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> This item belongs with the figure
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> as well as this sub item
        \end{itemize}
           \begin{onlyenv}<1>
               \begin{figure}
                   \includegraphics<1>[width=2cm]{example-image}
                 \end{figure}
           \end{onlyenv}
         \item<2-> This shows after the figure
         \item<3-> But still takes up space
         \item<4-> For long lists, the figure will not be visible anymore
          \end{itemize}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might have to play around with the value of `4cm`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know about `onlyenv`, seems very handy!